# Headless Chrome output javascript errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-headless

Is there any way to output js errors using `headless chrome`?

For example, this site https://labs.observepoint.com/ has this js error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !` and I need to log it in `headless chrome`

This is what I tried:
Start headless chrome with: `google-chrome --headless --enable-logging --v=1 --remote-debugging-port=9222`

And then run this code:

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');
CDP((client) => {
    // extract domains
    const {Network, Page} = client;
    // setup handlers
    Network.requestWillBeSent((params) => {
        console.log(params.request.url);
    });
    Page.loadEventFired(() => {
        client.close();
    });
    // enable events then start!
    Promise.all([
        Network.enable(),
        Page.enable()
    ]).then(() => {
        return Page.navigate({url: 'https://labs.observepoint.com/'});
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        client.close();
    });
}).on('error', (err) => {
    // cannot connect to the remote endpoint
    console.error(err);
});
```

But I don't know where the browser errors are logged

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `--enable-logging=v=1` in your command line. More information you can find here:  [enable-logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging).

Comment: Do you know where can I find the logs? There is no chrome_debug.log in this path ~/.config/google-chrome/Default

Comment: The commandline argument is "--enable-logging -v=1",  as you want to both set the verbosity and enable logging.  With that said, on the version I tested with (63.0) that tried to write to /usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chrome_debug.log,  which my normal user does not have access to and silently failed.

--enable-log=../../../tmp/log   made it log to /tmp/log,  but is a hacky workaround for the fact that using --enable-log=/tmp/log  tries to save to  /usr/lib64/chromium-browser//tmp/log


edit: also with all of that said, I don't even see JS errors in this log, so this doesn't seem to help OP